# Converting Text File to Dataframe and New Lines Causing Issues in Column

Tags: python, pandas

I am receiving very large .txt files that basically look like this:

```
FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | COMMENTS         |
-------------------------------------
Smith        | John      | normal comment |
Williams     | Kyle      | normal comment |
David        | Peter     | this is an example of a 
broken 
comment|
Jefferson     | Thomas    | normal comment|
```

As in it literally looks like this when I open the .txt file. I'm not trying to create a table for this post.

I am trying to convert the txt file into a DataFrame and have zero issues with most of the rows by just using "|" as the separator and stripping the white space. But new rows (and an unnamed column) are being created for rows that contain new lines -- like Peter David.

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | COMMENTS | Unnamed:3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | John | normal comment | nan |
| Williams | Kyle | normal comment | nan |
| David | Peter | this is an example of a | nan |
| broken | nan | nan | nan |
| comment | nan | nan | nan |
| Jefferson | Thomas | normal comment | nan |

The amount of new lines for comments like these also varies. How do I get rows in the comments column with new lines into a single line with a space?

I know it can't be as simple as using replace for all instances of '\n' with ' ' because that will kill the rows.

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | COMMENTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | John | normal comment |
| Williams | Kyle | normal comment |
| David | Peter | this is an example of a broken comment |
| Jefferson | Thomas | normal comment |

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any code to go off of, so this is my best shot.

```
FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | COMMENTS         |
-------------------------------------
Smith        | John      | normal comment |
Williams     | Kyle      | normal comment |
David        | Peter     | this is an example of a 
broken 
comment|
Jefferson     | Thomas    | normal comment|
```

You want to remove the new lines, and fix the comment. One option would be to read the line, until you encounter a `|`. Then, you know that you have reached the end of the comment. I haven't used `DataFrame` before, but I can describe one way to solve this without it. If you remove the header from the table, you'll have a string including:

```
Smith        | John      | normal comment |
Williams     | Kyle      | normal comment |
David        | Peter     | this is an example of a 
broken 
comment|
Jefferson     | Thomas    | normal comment|
```

Instead of trying to seperate the rows with just `\n`, try `|\n`. Example:

```py
table = # the rows (without header)
rows = table.split('|\n')
```

Now, taking the comment separately, you'll have:

```
this is an example of a 
broken 
comment
```

If you want to remove the lines, take the comment itself and remove the newlines before processing.
Of course, there are other ways (and possibly more elegant) of doing this.
By reading your question, I believe this should be implementable using whatever system you have already.